# how to handle a Specific Url in android webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, intentfilter

I want to open the link `https://appear.in/terochat-t192f` in my custom webview in my application. When I start a new Activity that contains this webview, I am faced with this page:

[image]

And when I click on the button "join conversation", I am faced with "page not found" like this:

[image]

I found out that I should handle the URL with intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml with:

```
<activity android:name=".MainSegment.Team.Team_Profile.Chatroom.VideoChatroomActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="appear.in"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it has't resolved my problem yet!

This is my Java code in the activity that contains this WebView:

```
public class VideoChatroomActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener{
    private AdvancedWebView teamChatWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_chatroom);
        
        teamChatWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_team_video_chat);
        teamChatWebView.setListener(this, this);
        teamChatWebView.addPermittedHostname("appear.in");
        teamChatWebView.loadUrl("https://appear.in/terochat-t192f");
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        teamChatWebView.onResume();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        teamChatWebView.onPause();
        // ...
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        teamChatWebView.onDestroy();
        // ...
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        teamChatWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!teamChatWebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
        // ...
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {

    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what will happen If you click into **Join conversation** button?

Comment: @TranHieu the second image appeared as i showed in the question! "Webpage not available"